# CSS: mysterious padding with postion absolute in table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour when trying to absolute position a div element inside a table-cell. To realise absolute positioning, I use a wrapper div element with `position:relative`:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="200px"></col>
        <col width="300px"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Caption 1</th>
            <th>Caption 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="wrapper"><div class="abs">abs</div></div></td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
     width: 100%;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

.abs {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b1j2gbn3/1/)**

As you can see, there is a gap between the wrapper div and the top of the containing table-cell. This gap will vanish if I change the `abs` element to `position:relative`.

So where does this gap come from and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you take `.abs` out of the normal page flow, `.wrapper` no longer has any content, so it collapses on itself and all you see is the border along the top of it.

It is in the vertical-middle of the cell because `middle` is the default `vertical-align` style for `td` and `th`s.

This can be better demonstrated if we add a non-breaking space in the mix:

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
.abs {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="200px"></col>
        <col width="300px"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Caption 1</th>
            <th>Caption 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="wrapper">&nbsp;
                    <div class="abs">abs</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much answered the question and it solves the problem within the fiddle. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my actual problem. I thought the fiddle would reproduce it nicely, but apparently it doesn't. But anyway, this should be the right answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could've helped. Could you expand on your bigger issue? Perhaps ask another question if appropriate?

Comment: Yes, I will probably ask another question as soon as I managed to reproduce this issue in a fiddle with `vertical-align: top;`. So far, I'm still not able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set dimensions to wrapper,

```
.wrapper {height: 30px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b1j2gbn3/2/

Else, the `.wrapper` height is 0 and table cell has `vertical-align: middle;` by default, so the blue border is in the middle of the cell.